# Splunk Charting Data Based on Type

Tags: charts, splunk, splunk-query

I have derived data from Splunk in the following format (Actual Format). But I want to format furthermore it in such a way that I can see which items are present in which categories, and which are missing (Expected Format). I am trying to chart it based on categoryID, but it's not working for me as I do not think max function is appropriate for this. Can anyone please help me know how can I achieve this

Tried using

```
| chart max(itemId) over itemId by categoryID
```

Actual Data

[image: Actual Format]

Expected Format Data:

[image: Expected Format]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it using..

```
| xyseries itemId categoryID itemId
```